# XPath to namespaced XML in Python?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, epub3

I am using lxml with xpath to parse an epub3, xhtml content file.

I want to select all the `li` nodes with the attribute `epub:type="footnote"`
as for example

```
<li epub:type="footnote" id="fn14"> ... </li>
```

I cannot find the right xpath expression for it.

The expression

```
//*[self::li][@id]
```

does select all the `li` nodes with attribute id, but when I try

```
//*[self::li][@epub:type]
```

I get the error

```
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
```

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body> 
        <section class="footnotes">
            <hr />
            <ol>
                <li id="fn1" epub:type="footnote">
                    <p>See foo</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to write the correct expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you declared the namespace prefix `epub` to lxml?

```
>>> tree.getroot().xpath(
...     "//li[@epub:type = 'footnote']", 
...     namespaces={'epub':'http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops'}
...     )
```

### Update per question update

The XHTML namespace is also tripping you up.  Try:

```
>>> tree.getroot().xpath(
...     "//xhtml:li[@epub:type = 'footnote']", 
...     namespaces={'epub':'http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops', 'xhtml': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'}
...     )
```

Comment: Indeed, but it didn't work.
`li = tree.getroot().xpath("//li[@epub:type = 'footnote']", namespaces={'epub':'http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops'})`

`print len(li)`

`>>> 0`


if I try to do 

`print(tree.getroot())`


the result is 
`<Element html at 0x7f30bb85b998>`

when I was expecting it to be:

`<Element {http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops} ...>`

Do you think that mean that the tree namespace is not http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops ?